# Is it possible to use Python to measure response time?

Tags: python

I'm running some experiments and I need to precisely measure participants' response time to questions. I know there are some commercial software, but I was wondering if I can do this with Python. Does python provides suitable functionality to measure the response time in millisecond unit?

Thank you,
Joon

Comment: When you Googled `python` and `time` did you learn anything?

Comment: I KNOW of the time module. I was wondering it is reliable enough to use in experimental environment where I have to precisely measure the response time. Maybe my question was not informative enough. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could measure the execution time between the options displayed and the input received.

http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

```
def whatYouWantToMeasure():
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer("whatYouWantToMeasure()", "from __main__ import test")
    print t.timeit(number=1)
```

Comment: I think by default t.timeit() will run the function 1000000 times instead of only once.To run it only once, you will need to change the code to - *print t.timeit(number=1)*

Answer (score 4):

Just do something like this:

```
from time import time
starttime = time()
askQuestion()
timetaken = time() - starttime
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the `timeit` module.

```
import timeit
```